# Check if the "tag" from the flash message match inside the template

Tags: django, templates, view

I am currently attempting to create a global message using tags from Django messages.

**Globaly**: I would like to use the tags from the messages to determine if the message is a warning, success, or something else.

for example,
my message inside my view:

```
messages.success(self.request, f'Success, your account has been deleted', 'success')
```

my template, HTML :

```
<p>
   {% if message.tag == success %}Success
   {% elif message.tag == welcome %}Welcome
   {% else %}Warning 
   {% endif%}
</p>
```

Alternatively, is it possible to directly display the tag string in my template, without condition ?

Comment: also not working if I use 
`{% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.INFO %}Info {% endif %}`
**Or**
`{% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.SUCCESS %}Success {% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: don't forgot "for".

Example

```
{% for message in messages %} 
  {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.SUCCESS %}Success {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

tags :

- DEBUG     debug
- INFO      info
- SUCCESS   success
- WARNING   warning
- ERROR     error